# Creating a thread and passing a struct to it

Tags: c, pthreads

I want to create n threads. Then pass them a struct each to populate that struct with data; such as a bool to keep track of whether the thread finished or was interrupted with a terminate signal.

```
n = 5; // For testing.

pthread_t threads[n];
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
   pthread_create(&threads[i], &thread_structs[i], &functionX);
```

Assume that thread_structs has been malloced.

Inside the `functionX()` Notice function doesn't have parameters. Should I make a parameter for the struct? Or where I am passing the struct is okay?

How do I point to the struct that I just passed to the function?

Comment: Any reason why you would pass it as void instead of the struct type?

Comment: "void*" is the generic pointer type - all pointers can decay to a `void*` without a conversion error. That allows for a generic definition of pthread_create without having to know about custom/future types. if it was defined to take a `thread_struct*` and you wanted to pass it a pointer to an int, you'd have to do a cast.

Comment: or in simpler terms: taking a void* is a way of saying it'll take a pointer to anything. the down side is that it does actually arrive as void* and you have to cast it back on your side of the interface. Which is supposed to remind you "this could be a pointer to anything, be careful"

Comment: Ok I see why it is useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how you use pthread_create:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html

```
   int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                      void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

The 3rd argument is your routine, the fourth is an argument that will be forwarded to your routine. Your routine should look like this:

```
void* functionX(void* voidArg)
{
    thread_struct* arg = (thread_struct*)voidArg;
    ...
```

and the pthread call should be:

```
pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, functionX, &thread_structs[i]);
```

(unless you have a pthread_attr_t to supply as the second argument).

Comment: Indeed - fixed. Gets a little fiddly typing the non-alphanum symbols on the damn kindle :)

Comment: I decided to add another parameter to the functionX. Compiler throws "too many arguments to function 'pthread_create'. Is there a way around this besides putting all the parameters into my struct that way I can pass as many as I want?

Comment: As you suspected, you can only pass it the one argument, so you have to put all the args into the struct you're passing the address of. If you don't want your thread_struct cluttered with launch arguments, you could always make a "thread_create_struct" and include a thread_struct* member. That gives you some separation of concerns, but also might be over kill :)

Comment: @MikeJohn: you can't choose how many arguments get passed to your thread function.  The `pthread` system dictates to you exactly what will be passed to your function (it is a single `void *` argument, the value of which you get to specify).  You have to bend your code to work with the system; the system won't bend to suit your whims. That said, the system is actually flexible enough to get any information you need to your thread function — it just has to be done via a single pointer to data of arbitrary complexity.

Comment: Yeah. It was an easy workaround with a global variable. I just had to ask that one bit to make sure there wasn't a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Declare `functionX`

```
void* function functionX(void* data) {
}
```

Then cast `data` to the whatever the pointer type of `&thread_structs[i]` is and use it as you please.